# How to format date fields before save in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I used this in AppController:

```
Time::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/YYYY');
```

The date field in my form is a input type "text" to allow my user writes something like **31/12/2015**.

However when I try to save (MySQL date) I get some errors of **Time Class** because inside the table the value now is 00-00-0000

[Alunos Controller code](http://pastebin.com/E1FpFfdE)

Thanks !

Comment: What type do you use to store date and time in mysql. Can you update your question with code which inserts user input in database ?

Comment: in mysql date is stored in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. so by changing the date format to this before saving may help you to solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My final solution was this on bootstrap:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

Type::build('time')->useImmutable();
Type::build('date')->useImmutable()->useLocaleParser();
Type::build('datetime')->useImmutable()->useLocaleParser();
Type::build('timestamp')->useImmutable();

\Cake\I18n\Time::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
\Cake\I18n\Date::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
\Cake\I18n\FrozenTime::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
\Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

\Cake\I18n\I18n::locale('pt-BR'); //new !

Type::build('decimal')->useLocaleParser();
Type::build('float')->useLocaleParser();
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe this could help someone.

```
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options) {
    $entity->dateField = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($entity->dateField));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just creating a new application with a fresh database, delete does dates having 0000-00-00 and change the column definition so it can accept nulls. Using 0000-00-00 for dates is usually a really bad thing as only errors and bugs can come out of it :)

**Edit based on the comments below**

It seems like the problem was getting a string field to be parsed from the local date format to what php can understand. For this task you just need to configure the `DateTimeType` class to parse the dates using a locale-aware format as described here http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#parsing-localized-datetime-data

```
// In bootstrap.php or AppController or your controller action:

use Cake\Database\Type;
...

Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser();
```

You can also set the locale parser to parse a specific format. For the code above to work, make sure you set your application to use a locale:

```
I18n::locale('fr-FR')
```

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo but in MySQL the date format is YYYY-MM-DD and how can I be able to insert date using this format without functions like STR_TO_DATE( "31/05/2014", "%m/%d/%Y" ) or  ? In Cake 1.2 I used a Behavior called DateFormatter.

Comment: If you are using Time objects the ORM will know exactly what format to use in the database.

Comment: I've tried Time::$defaultLocale = 'pt-BR'; in AppController but the problem persists... and 'timezone' => 'BRT', in Database too

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: try to save() a date from a input text dd/mm/yyyy without convert to yyyy-mm-dd and get error

Comment: Why are you trying to save a string in the date field instead of converting it to a Time object?

Comment: @lorenzo input text for date is a pattern in my job place ! They don't like  3 "selects" fields for a date field

Comment: @celsowm Improved my answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy solution insert date format in CakePHP 3.x in Models and custom out views:**

Insert **['rule' => ['date','dmy']]**

**Example**

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    ...

    $validator
        ->add('demo_example_date', 'valid', ['rule' => ['date','dmy']]) //Format valid '30-12-2015' or '30-12-05'
        ->requirePresence('demo_example_date', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('factura_fecha');

    ...

    return $validator;
}
```

Out view, set AppController

```
    ...    

    use Cake\I18n\Time;
    use Cake\Database\Type;
    Time::$defaultLocale = 'es-ES';
    Time::setToStringFormat('dd-MM-YYYY');
    Type::build('datetime')->useLocaleParser();

    class AppController extends Controller
    {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me using Postgres.

File config/app.php

in variable Datasources['default'] add command 'SET datestyle TO ISO, DMY' to init

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [            
            'init' => ['SET datestyle TO ISO, DMY '],
        ],
```

in mysql
https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SET/SETDATESTYLE.htm

Comment: SQLServer: 'init' => ['SET DATEFORMAT DMY'],